# qfield will not highlight selected feature

Tags: qfield

When selecting a feature in qfield it will not highlight the way it did in past versions. I do not know why this is happening. Was this taken out from the past update?

Answer (score 1):

According to Denis Rouzaud, this will be fixed in the next update. You can check it out in this APK.

"""

This has been fixed and will be available in upcoming 1.0.4 (still this week).

If you have the chance to test the APK it would be very helpful, see the link here (usually you need armv7 builds)
https://github.com/opengisch/QField/commit/0d19e80fd1d85764480329b6334fbb05bc662fe3#commitcomment-33180529

Cheers,

Denis

"""